# Tesseract OCR not splitting lines correctly

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

for my application I need to use OCR to extract text from invoices. To achieve this, I crop the invoice I need to scan to the individual columns and put these cropped images through tesseract. For the majority of the columns this works perfectly, but there are a few where it doesn't split the lines and it outputs everything in the same string.

What I am currently trying is to use the string.split() method using "\n" and "\r" as parameters.

The code below shows how exactly I am attempting to split the output into an array of strings:

```
public string[] ProcessFile(Image InputImage)
        {
            Bitmap WorkImage = new Bitmap(InputImage);
            string[] Output;

            Tesseract.TesseractEngine Engine = new TesseractEngine("./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractAndCube);
            Page RawOutput = Engine.Process(WorkImage);
            string ConvertedOutput = RawOutput.GetText();
            Output = ConvertedOutput.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            Engine.Dispose();
            return Output;
        }
```

For columns that contain values like
"product 1"
"product 2"
"product 3"
etc
this works just fine, but when the column contains individual numbers, like so:
"1"
"4"
"12"
"6"

It only returns "14126".

I hope anyone is able to point me towards a solution to this.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the GitHub wiki of Tesseract? Can this be of any help: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams?

Comment: @BernoulliIT I have now, and I believe this is aimed for people who use Tesseract from the command line. Therefor, I have been unable to call these parameters in C#.

Comment: The API you are using doesn't provide any settings property / class to define specific arguments used during recognition? Please do some reverse engineering on the tesseract c# classes / interfaces.

Comment: @BernoulliIT after a bit of fiddling around with the pagesegmentationmode, I managed to get it to work. Setting it to PageSegMode.SingleBlock did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the GitHub wiki of Tesseract https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc

You can use the `PageSegmentationMode`, `PageSegMode.SingleBlock` to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Link is dead. Please avoid make your answers only link so they dont become useless

Comment: Hyperlink updated, documentation was moved in GitHub.